# Overlap between rows in two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, transformation

Want to identify the overlap between two dataframes with columns of start & end ranges as a new dataframe to then operate over. My solution was to do an outer merge & mask, but this seems inefficient. Is there a more performant approach?

Example data:

```
#x & y measure values along a segment distance - where do they overlap?
#Note: start_ & end_ are often continuous, but not always (see df1 rows 3-4 & 7-8)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Segment": ["a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",],
    "start_x": [0.000, 6.347, 0.000, 11.659, 11.853, 12.028, 12.548, 12.864, 13.055, 13.302], 
    "end_x": [6.347, 14.452, 11.659, 11.788, 12.028, 12.548, 12.864, 12.956, 13.302, 22.831],
    "value_x": np.random.randint(0,50,10)
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Segment": ["a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"],
    "start_y": [0.000, 0.000, 2.790, 3.370, 11.659, 11.788, 12.028, 12.548, 12.645, 12.780, 12.864, 13.055], 
    "end_y": [14.452, 2.790, 3.370, 11.659, 11.788, 12.028, 12.548, 12.645, 12.780, 12.864, 13.055, 22.831],
    "value_y": np.random.randint(0,50,12)
    })
```

My solution:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Segment', how='outer') #outer merge not ideal
range_overlaps = (
    ((df3['start_x'] <= df3['start_y']) & (df3['end_x'] >= df3['end_y'])) | #y between x
    ((df3['start_x'] < df3['end_y']) & (df3['end_x'] >= df3['end_y'])) | #y ends before x
    ((df3['start_x'] >= df3['start_y']) & (df3['end_x'] <= df3['end_y'])) #x between y
)

df3.loc[~range_overlaps] = np.nan #NaN the rows that don't meet criteria
df3.dropna(inplace=True)

df3['start_z'] = df3[['start_x', 'start_y']].max(axis=1)
df3['end_z'] =  df3[['end_x', 'end_y']].min(axis=1)
df3['value_z'] = df3['value_x'] + df3['value_y']
```

Comment: all these seem fine, the only part might be, after you got `range_overlaps`, you don't have to set nan, just do `df3 = df3[range_overlaps]`

Comment: Thank you @DaSong - this does simplify the example. In some situations I want to keep/report on NaN cases, in which I think would need this operation.